# How to detect if JavaScript (ES6) class has a non-default constructor?

Tags: es6-class

I would like to know by some form of reflection or other means if a given ES6 class has a user-written non-default constructor, or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming that user-provided constructor has one argument or more*, you can do that by checking the `length` property of the function(class). But if the constructor *takes no argument*, there is simply no way as far as I know

```js
function Person(fName, lName) {
    this.firstName = fName;
    this.lastName = lName
}
console.log(Person.length);

function Person2() {}
console.log(Person2.length);

class Person3 {
    constructor(f,l) {}
}
console.log(Person3.length);

class Person4 {
}
console.log(Person4.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke the `Classname.prototype.constructor.toString()` (where `Classname` is the inspected class name) and get the source string for the class. Which you can then parse and see if it was a constructor declared or not.

Presumably, you need a decent parser for that, but it's another story.

References:

- http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function.prototype.tostring